# Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#-4.0, nunit, asp.net-mvc-3, rhino, mvccontrib-testhelper

I have a sample ASP.NET MVC 3 web application that is following Jonathan McCracken's Test-Drive Asp.NET MVC (great book , by the way) and I have stumbled upon a problem. Note that I'm using MVCContrib, Rhino and NUnit.

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldSetLoggedInUserToViewBag() {
        var todoController = new TodoController();
        var builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
        builder.InitializeController(todoController);

        builder.HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("John Doe"), null);

        Assert.That(todoController.Index().AssertViewRendered().ViewData["UserName"], Is.EqualTo("John Doe"));
    }
```

The code above always throws this error:

> System.AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The controller action code is the following:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        ViewData.Model = Todo.ThingsToBeDone;
        ViewBag.UserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        return View();
    }
```

From what I have figured out, the app seems to crash because of the two assignements in the controller action. However, I cannot see how there are wrong!?

Can anyone help me pinpoint the solution to this problem.

Thank you.

**Edit 1**

I've done some experiments to see what the problem is.
When removing the `ViewData,Model` assignment the problem transcends in `Expected result to be of type ViewResult. It is actually of type ViewResult.`. The `ViewData` assignment is so basic that I do not think that it is the problem so I think there is something wrong with either Rhino or MVCcontrib in conjunction with MVC 3.

I also have the following test written earlier for the same controller action:

```
        [Test]
    public void ShouldDisplayAListOfTodoItems() {
        Assert.That(((ViewResult)new TodoController().Index()).ViewData.Model, Is.EqualTo(Todo.ThingsToBeDone));
    }
```

This one fails now with `System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object` probably becuase there's no HttpContext set up for this particular test. When removing the `ViewBag` assignment, everything is ok.

Hope that makes the problem more clear.

**Edit 2**

When debugging the code after removing the `ViewData.Model` assignment, it throws a different error: `System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the `ViewBag` assignment.

Comment: On which line exactly is the exception thrown and could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Well, it dies when I try to assign something into the ViewData. So, if I comment the two lines where I assign stuff to ViewData and ViewBag it does not die.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I've knocked this one down. As I have suspected, it was because of MVCContrib. Mind that I am using MVC 3 Beta which is not yet officially supported by MVCContrib. With that in mind, I have downloaded the latest MVCContrib sources for MVC 3 branch.

Go to [MVCContrib Sources](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), switch to the **mvc3** branch, download, and build the binaries with the attached bat. Then, include the needed files into your solution.

Well, this will probably get fixed in a future stable release, but I guess it might be useful to others. Thank you Darin for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldSetLoggedInUserToViewBag() 
{
    // arrange
    var todoController = new TodoController();
    var builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
    builder.InitializeController(todoController);

    builder.HttpContext
        .Stub(x => x.User)
        .Return(new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("John Doe"), null));

    // act
    var actual = todoController.Index();

    // assert
    actual.AssertViewRendered();
    Assert.That(todoController.ViewData["UserName"], Is.EqualTo("John Doe"));
}
```

and the controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    ViewBag.UserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    return View(Todo.ThingsToBeDone);
}
```

Remark: I would include the information into the view model and avoid using `ViewData/ViewBag`. It is not strongly typed and it forces you to use magic quotes.

Comment: I'll try your code ASAP and get back on you on the result.ViewBag is dynamic, and does not require quoting. It's a new addition to MVC 3.

Comment: Nope, does not work. It throws an error saying that:
You are trying to set an expectation on a property that was defined to use PropertyBehavior.
Instead of writing code such as this: mockObject.Stub(x => x.SomeProperty).Return(42);
You can use the property directly to achieve the same result: mockObject.SomeProperty = 42;

Comment: @Interfector, right, so I am mistaken. What if you assign it directly as you did in your example. Also what if you no longer use ViewBag/ViewData in your controller action. Could you try isolating the problem?

Comment: See my edit. I think the HttpContext is not setup correctly by MVCContrib.